# Basic optimization problem of n 1 degree variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let's say I have the function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3$ and the constraint that $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$ with every $x_1,x_2,x_3\geq0$. I want to find $\operatorname{argmax} f$. It is pretty obvious that in order to maximize this function, I will find which of $a,b,c$ is the largest and it's corresponding variable will be $1$ while the other $2$ are $0$.

For example, I have $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = 7x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3$, then $\operatorname{argmax} f$ is simply $x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=0$.

My question concerns how to prove this is true for any number of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ where you simply choose the $x_i$ with the largest coefficient to be $1$ and all the others to be $0$. Any help of where to start would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to maximize $\sum_j c_j x_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_j &= 1 \\
x_j &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $j$}
\end{align}
Let $M = \max_j c_j$ with argmax $j^*$.  As you have noted, setting $x_{j^*}=1$ and all other $x_j=0$ satisfies the constraints and yields a lower bound of $M$ on the maximum objective value.  To show that this $M$ is also an upper bound, note that
$$\sum_j c_j x_j \le \sum_j M x_j = M \sum_j x_j = M \cdot 1 = M.$$

(In terms of linear programming, the dual multiplier of $M$ for the equality constraint provides a certificate of optimality.)