# Closed form solution for the following problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I would like to know if there is a closed-form solution to these optimization problems:

$$ \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} c^Tx$$ and $$\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} c^Tx$$
and both restricted to the following conditions:

$$x\ge0$$
$$\mathbf{1}^Tx= 1$$
Also $c\in\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Nevertheless, I would predict that the reason is related to the dialog box that appeared when you clicked "Ask Question", which contained the text "Provide details and any research.  3.  When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried."  Neither of these is present in your Question.

Comment: Yes, you should look into the Simplex Method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic optimization problem of n 1 degree variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840514/basic-optimization-problem-of-n-1-degree-variables)

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you, what about the minimum one.

Comment: @7337dtd for the minimum, the argument is analogous.  Just replace max with min throughout, let $m=\min_j c_j$, and show that $\sum_j c_j \ge m$.

Comment: @User8128 Hi, could you give a link that provides the closed-form solution, I have searched but could not find one. Thank you.

Comment: @7337dtd the argument still works if $\min_i c_i < 0$.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you. I think this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we have
$\max_k c_k = \max_{x \in \Sigma} x^T c$, so the answer is $\max_k c_k$.

With $\Sigma = \{ x | x_k \ge 0, \sum_k x_k = 1 \}$.

A similar analysis applies to $\min$ with the obvious result.